Why is Hapticity of σ(C5H5) 1, and not 5?
This might sound as a very poor question It's disturbing me right now so I will ask anyway. Why is the hapticity of $\sigma$$\ce{C5H5-}$ 1?
Now I am having this question because we know that $\ce{C5H5-}$ is a resonance stabilised carbanion with 3 electron pairs in resonance , and hence making it aromatic.

Now my question is that, in coordination sphere , when $\ce{C5H5-}$ will be donating only 2 electrons owing to its negative charge (I am not talking about the ($\pi$$\ce{C5H5-}$ in which all the three electron pairs are donated), then should it not be $\eta^5$?
The reason being that basically there is Not a single carbon atom where all the negative charge is present. When negative charge is being distributed among the 5 carbon atoms (due to resonance) , each carbon will be having a partial charge of -0.2. So why is it still $\eta^1$?
Why should all the carbon atoms of the ring , among which the whole -1 charge is distributed , not be linked with the Central Metal atom?

See the illustration here to discern $\sigma$ and $\pi$ for this very ligand.

This question is similar to: What do 'sigma' and 'pi' in front of ligands in the formula of a coordination compound mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Buttonwood I had seen that question... however my question is different because I am asking about the hapticity in both the sigma and pi-cyclobutadienyl...whereas the question you have shared is concerning mainly about 'what' sigma and pi-cyclobutadienyl are.

Um I would like to know if there is something I can improve in this question or my way of asking the question (because the downvote)

You depict the mesomeric formulae of the isolated $\ce{C5H^-_5}$ anion. You correctly state none of the carbon atoms carries the negative charge fully - it is shared among the carbon atoms (probably better if now presuming electrons as a wave: distributed all across the molecule).  The charge of this anion is not a discrete item one could localize, it is not moving around the cycle.
It is by definition that $\ce{\sigma-{}C5H5}$ is of hapticity $\eta^1$ because in this mode only one specific atom of the anion is engaged in binds to an other molecule or atom, e.g. the two ligands to the right of Ti in the illustration below:

(source)
It is a snapshot of the molecule's structure. It does not state, nor exclude reaction conditions where perhaps an other single carbon atom of the anion binds to Ti.
As you see, this does not exclude that there are other bonding pattern, for instance $\ce{\pi-{}C5H5}$ (which in this case happens to be $\eta^5$) via $\pi$ bonds involving multiple carbon atoms of the $\ce{C5H^-_5}$ anion  simultaneously.

Thanks a lot  @buttonwood
